# Mvc4 on Button click not being forwarded to [HttpPost] action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, http-get

in my Controller I have these actions

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid )
            {
                var regUser = _db.Users.Create();

                regUser.UserName = user.UserName;
                regUser.Password = user.Password;

                _db.Users.Add(regUser);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

and my view is like this

```
@model BootstrappingMvc.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BootstrapLayout.empty.cshtml";
}


<form class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register New User</h2>
    <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.UserName, new{@placeholder = "UserName"})</div>
    <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.Password, new{@placeholder ="Password"})</div>
    <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.ConfirmPassword, new{@placeholder = "Confirm Password"})</div>

    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

here is my `RegisterModel`

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Shouldn't I be forwarded to `[httpPost]`  action of the controller when the register button is clicked by user? Right now it takes me to `[httpget]` action when button is clicked and I get this in browser `http://localhost:47944/Portal/Register?UserName=Biplov+&Password=123456&ConfirmPassword=123456`

I really can't uderstand how I am getting those values in browser and why I'm not being forwarded to `[httpPost]` action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Register","Controller to be forwarded",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register New User</h2>
    <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.UserName, new{@placeholder = "UserName"})</div>
    <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.Password, new{@placeholder ="Password"})</div>
    <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.ConfirmPassword, new{@placeholder = "Confirm Password"})</div>

    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
}
```

I think using Html helper to create form and adding parameter `FormMethod.Post` makes thing sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like thisin view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "yourcontroller"))
    {
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register New User</h2>
<div class ="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.UserName, new{@placeholder = "UserName"})</div>
<div class ="input-block-level">@Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.Password, new{@placeholder ="Password"})</div>
<div class ="input-block-level">@Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.ConfirmPassword, new{@placeholder = "Confirm Password"})</div>

<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following line in your code to post view on controller Post Action

`<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="Register">`

`<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register New User</h2>`

`<div class ="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.UserName,new{@placeholder = "UserName"})</div>`

`<div class ="input-block-level">@Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.Password,new{@placeholder ="Password"})</div>`
`<div class ="input-block-level">@Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.ConfirmPassword,new{@placeholder = "Confirm Password"})</div>`

`<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button></form>`